# subdivision surface looks horrible

Tags: subdivision-surface

hi after enabling subdivision surface i get this error

[image]

[image]

basically i cannot subdv because i get weird errors what i want is to do something similar to

looks horrible and if i select the ring and bevel it to fix it , it looks horribler too

[image]

this is the top of the cilinder topology i do not see why looks like that when added subsurf

[image]

Comment: Hello, the top of your cylinder has a weird topology

Comment: hello @moonboots how can i improve that? is there any tutorial you can recomend me

Comment: added new post showing topology is default i dont know anything about topology i just extrude and bool

Comment: It looks as if the top has had Grid Fill applied to it for some reason? Can you show the first image in Edit mode?

Comment: A nice reference for topology: topologyguides.com good topology is important when using the subdivision surface modifier

Comment: is already on edit mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Supporting Edge Loops Needed

The pinching you're seeing with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier on your cylinder can happen when there are no supporting edge loops near the edge between the side of the cylinder and its cap.

Here's a screenshot of how I might approach the topology for your shape:

[image]

Here's a good reference for topology: https://topologyguides.com/

Comment: how do i do a edge loop?

Comment: how do add an edge loop?, control + R ?

Comment: thank you, it worked i just had to add some loops around the cuts